# Apache POI excel file read same code giving different results for two different sheets

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng

I am trying data driven testing with two different sheets in one single excel sheet. But what I observed is same code gave two different results when I tried executing a two different test cases. It was strange. One sheet data got properly processed but for another, same code gave Null pointer exception on a particular line. Below is the code.

```
@DataProvider(name="testdataforinvalidvalues")
    public static Object[][] readexcelretobjinvalidval() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Data provider called");
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = assignworkbook();
        HSSFSheet s = workbook.getSheetAt(2);
        String sp = s.getSheetName();
        System.out.println(sp);
        HSSFRow row = s.getRow(0);
        int rownum=s.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int colnum=row.getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println(rownum);
        System.out.println(colnum);

        //System.out.println(rownum);
        //System.out.println(colnum);
        Object data[][] = new Object[rownum][colnum];
        List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i=0;i<rownum-1;i++) {
            row = s.getRow(i+1);
            for(int j=0;j<colnum;j++) {
                **HSSFCell c  = row.getCell(j);**
                //l.add(c.getStringCellValue());
                data[i][j]=c.getStringCellValue();
            }
        }

        return data;
```

The line in the code HSSFCell c  = row.getCell(j); which I tried to show in bold just below for loop is throwing null pointer exception.

The test case which I tried to run is as follows.

```
@Test(dataProvider="testdataforinvalidvalues",dataProviderClass=Excel_Util.class)
    public void testsignupdatafieldsinvval(String email, String password) {

        Syncutil.Implicitwait();
        System.out.println("Test case called");
        try {

            getdriver().get("https://www."+csvreaderutil.csvread().get(0).toString()+"/");
            Marathishd marathishdpage = PageFactory.initElements(getdriver(), Marathishd.class);
            Signuppagemarathishd signup = marathishdpage.letsbeginclick();
            signup.emailid.sendKeys(email);
            signup.password.sendKeys(password);
            Syncutil.Explicitwait(signup.invalidemailerrormessage);
            Syncutil.Explicitwait(signup.invalidpassworderrormessage);
            Syncutil.Explicitwait(signup.enteremailmessage);
            Assert.assertEquals(signup.enteremailmessage.getText(), "Enter your Email ID");
            Assert.assertEquals(signup.invalidemailerrormessage.getText(), "Please enter correct Email");
            Assert.assertEquals(signup.invalidpassworderrormessage.getText(), "Please enter 4 to 20 characters password without any spaces");
            


        }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception");}
    }
```

I am confused why the data provider code behaved differently for two different sheets.Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: With NullPointerExceptions, you need to look at the stack trace. The code above is useless without the xls files that produce the issue. For instance, getRow can return null, you really need to check the row is not null before trying to use the row to get cells.

Comment: Sheet rowIterator() is the safest row to iterate rows - it will automatically skip empty rows.